# How to select, duplicate, and rename multiple columns in tibble with tidy evaluation semantics?

Tags: r, tidyverse, nse

I'd like to copy a set of variables in my tibble so I can have `variable_unmodified` and `variable` values in downstream evaluation. I've come up with a hacky version using the old-style underscore NSE `select_()` function and `.dots`, but would like to use the newer NSE approach of tidy evaluation semantics.

This does what I want:

```
tibble_to_max <- tibble(
  "a_col" = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  "max_1" = c("3;4", "2{3}4", "7", ".{1}"),
  "max_2" = c("3;4", "2{3}4", "7", ".{1}")
)

cols_to_max <- c("max_1", "max_2")

unparsed_names <-  paste0(cols_to_max, "_unparsed")

tibble_to_max %>%
  bind_cols(select_(., .dots = setNames(cols_to_max, unparsed_names)))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a_col max_1 max_2 max_1_unparsed max_2_unparsed
  <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>
1     1   3;4   3;4            3;4            3;4
2     2 2{3}4 2{3}4          2{3}4          2{3}4
3     3     7     7              7              7
4     4  .{1}  .{1}           .{1}           .{1}
```

But if I try to do it with `select()` and `!!`, `.dots` doesn't work as I expected:

```
tibble_to_max %>%
  bind_cols(select(., .dots = setNames(!!cols_to_max, !!unparsed_names)))
```

The columns are not named as desired:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a_col max_1 max_2 .dots1 .dots2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1     1   3;4   3;4    3;4    3;4
2     2 2{3}4 2{3}4  2{3}4  2{3}4
3     3     7     7      7      7
4     4  .{1}  .{1}   .{1}   .{1}
```

What is the correct way to do this? Also, bonus points for avoiding defining `unparsed_names` as a separate variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CPak for getting me on the right path. This accomplishes what I was shooting for, and uses tidy evaluation semantics instead of `select_()`:

```
tibble_to_max <- tibble(
  "a_col" = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  "max_1" = c("3;4", "2{3}4", "7", ".{1}"),
  "max_2" = c("3;4", "2{3}4", "7", ".{1}")
)

cols_to_max <- c("max_1", "max_2")

tibble_to_max %>%
  bind_cols(
    select_at(., 
      .vars = !!cols_to_max, 
      .funs = funs(paste0(., "_unparsed"))
      )
    )
```

Comment: `Error in !cols_to_max : invalid argument type`. Then I changed `.vars = !!cols_to_max` to `.vars = cols_to_max` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

Your data

```
tibble_to_max <- tibble(
  "a_col" = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  "max_1" = c("3;4", "2{3}4", "7", ".{1}"),
  "max_2" = c("3;4", "2{3}4", "7", ".{1}")
)
```

Solution using `nest`, then copy the nested data all at once, then `unnest`. I use `rename_all` to rename the columns in `data_copy`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble_to_max %>%
  nest(-a_col) %>%
  mutate(data_copy = data) %>%
  mutate(data_copy = map(data_copy, ~.x %>% rename_all(funs(paste0(., "_unparsed"))))) %>% 
  unnest(data, data_copy)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a_col max_1 max_2 max_1_unparsed max_2_unparsed
  <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>
1     1   3;4   3;4            3;4            3;4
2     2 2{3}4 2{3}4          2{3}4          2{3}4
3     3     7     7              7              7
4     4  .{1}  .{1}           .{1}           .{1}
```

Comment: That gets the values of the output tibble as I desire, but doesn't rename them. I think it's equivalent to doing this: `tibble_to_max %>% bind_cols(select(., !!cols_to_max))`